# How to limit the results when using CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy, dropwizard

I have inherited a groovy code base (that among other things) uses Hibernate as an ORM as part of Dropwizard and I've in the process of updating the dependencies I start seeing the following warnings.

```
org.hibernate.orm.deprecation: HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
```

As an experiment I tried updating one of the queries to use the new `CriteriaQuery` API. However pretty quickly I ran into an issue, the old code uses `setMaxResults()`. I assume under the hood this is using the `LIMIT` to limit the number of results.

How to I limit the results of a `CriteriaQuery` to `1`?

A related question, how do I do pagination with `CriteriaQuery`?

I tried reading through the Hibernate 5.3 users guide, (especially chapter [16 the the new API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria)) searing for "limits" and "max results" and such and all the talk I could find was in the "[Legacy Hibernate Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-criteria)".

I'd be happy to provide some example code if it helps, but you could just use the example from the manual ([Example 534. Selecting an attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-typedquery-expression)) and show how to enhance it by limiting the results.

Comment: Hey did you find anything?

Comment: @user1735921 I'm afraid not. I'm just living with the warnings.

Comment: I found it, you have to create an instance of org.hibernate.query.Query from session manager or entity manager whatever you are using from CriteriaQuery and then you can set max results and offset..

Answer (score 2):

Define `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` on the `Query` like this (offset=0 and limit=10):

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(10).getResultList());
```

Answer (score -3):

To paginate you just have to set the first and max (assuming you're passing in a [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) Object:

```
criteria.setFirstResult(pageable.gotOffset());
criteria.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
```

Also, to limit, just call:

```
Criteria queryCriteria = session.createCriteria(MonthlySubscriber.class);
queryCriteria.setFirstResult(0);
queryCriteria.setMaxResults(1);
monthlySubscriberList = queryCriteria .list();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I don't think I have a `Query` object, I think I have a `CriteriaQuery` object, and I don't see a `limit` method on that. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html

Comment: Question is about CriteriaQuery not Criteria. Read the question carefully first.

Comment: That's very similar: you can `TypedQuery<Entity> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);` and use `query` to `setMaxResults()` and `setFirstResults()`.